# std::cout segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, cout

Is there any reason that overuse of `cout` would result in a segmentation fault.

A piece of code that iterates through a matrix, then potentially recursively iterates through parts of the matrix again, contains the lines:

```
matrix matrix::topLevelFunction( void )
{
     for (int i=1; i<NRows-1; i++)
     {
             cout << "\rRow = " << i+1 << " / " << NRows << "    " << flush;
             for (int j=1; j<NCols-1; j++)
             {
                 recursiveFunction(i, j)
             }
      }
}

void matrix::recursiveFunction(int i, int j)
{
    double min;
    if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == NRows-1 || j == NCols-1)
    { }
    else
    {
        min = data[i][j] + 10;
        for (int row = -1; row <= 1; ++ row)
        {
            for (int col = -1; col <= 1; ++ col)
            {
                if (row != 0 && col != 0 && data[i+row][j+row] < min)
                    min = data[i+row][j+col];
            }
        }
        if (data[i][j] <= min)
        {
            data[i][j] = min + 0.0001;
            for (int row = -1; row <= 1; ++ row)
            {
                for (int col = -1; col <= 1; ++ col)
                {
                    if (row != 0 && col != 0)
                        recursiveFunction(i + row, j + col);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When the `cout` is left in, the function seg faults after a certain number of rows (~100 depending on the system it's run on), without it it runs to completion.

Is flushing stdout too many times causing this problem?

Comment: Could you show us the `recursiveFunction`?

Comment: have you run this through the debugger? It should highlight exactly where it's segfaulting. The code looks okay, `flush` is unusual here, normally I'd expect to see an `endl` - which should take care of things...

Comment: I am not sure but isn't it a problem: `if (row != 0 && col != 0 && data[i+row][j+row] < min)`? Possibly it should be: `if (row != 0 && col != 0 && data[i+row][j+col] < min)`.